# Navbar color is not full width

Tags: html, css, width, navbar, nav

I am trying to create a full-width navbar, but it does not go full width.

This is the part of the CSS of the nav:

[image]

This is what it looks:

[image]

Comment: I think you should use `width: 100vh;` to the nav bar element. Could you link the full code if this dosen't work? I would like to see it to help you.

Comment: You will have to provide bit more information like how is nav placed inside of your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i was able to solve your problem. You are using bootstrap in your html. Bootstrap has an element with class "container" and it has a media query at min-width: 1200px that sets the max-width of the container class to 1140px. WHich is why you're nav bar can't go wider than 1140px.

To solve this problem, the best way is to simply change your container class to .my-container or something similar.

Here's an example:

HTML

```
<div class="my-container"> 
    <nav>navbar with 100% width...</nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.my-container {
    width:100%;
}
nav {
    width:100%;
}
```

That will fix your problem.

Comment: I've tried everything you said, all the widths are on 100%. I tried to create a codepen file but it didn't work, I upload the files on a rar , pls help me :( link: https://www.mediafire.com/file/0kqd1c6wjb3scvz/index.rar/file

Comment: I found your problem and i was able to solve it, check out my updated answer above!

Comment: glad i could help !

Answer (score 0):

when width is set to 100%, it takes up 100% of the width of its parent.

so I would advise check the width of the parent, and maybe its parent's parent if thats where the problem occurs.

You can press option+command+J and open up the elements. There by hovering over the containers you where the problem arised.

otherwise, i can't help much more with the information you gave.

Comment: I've tried everything you said, all the widths are on 100%. I tried to create a codepen file but it didn't work, I upload the files on a rar , pls help me :( link: mediafire.com/file/0kqd1c6wjb3scvz/index.rar/file

Comment: I mainly added a "margin: none" on * and changed the header element slightly and some other minor things since the codepen refused use your bootstrap and aos etc links. I tried not to change too much since i have other things to do. Keeep up the good work. here it is https://codepen.io/iluvmommy/pen/PoZOKgL

Comment: I put the same html but it stills the same, anyways thanks you, you're a very cool man!

Comment: I think that the problem is with   this part, because when I erase it the navbar is full width:                                                                                                                
    <header id="inicio"></header>

Comment: I fixed!!!!! I think that is the order, the navbar is above the header

Answer (score 0):

I think it has a parent div or any parent tag I might not be able to tell whats wrong by only looking at styling I might need your html but I think this might help
note I added bootstrap

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```